# 5.4 Linux kernel on x86 panics with alignment exception when kexec'ed from 6.1 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, 64bit, x86, kexec

The boot chain here is UEFI -> 6.1.14 kernel built with EFI stub, initramfs loads and checks 5.4.109 kernel, then kexecs it.
CPU is a 2-core Intel Atom N6210.
When booted this way, at startup when the 5.4 kernel releases the second CPU, it immediately panics with an alignment exception.
The same kernel image works fine when booted from EFI, or booted via kexec by the 5.4.109 kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be due to [split-lock detection](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Splitlock-Hurts-Gaming).

The 6.1 kernel enabled the Intel split-lock detection feature on this CPU - it causes an alignment exception whenever an atomic operation spans cache lines. In newer kernels such as that one, it will WARN, BUG, panic or slow down depending on boot-time settings when this happens.

This stayed enabled through the `kexec`. The older kernel had no idea it was enabled, its alignment-check exception handler just panics, and since the older kernel had not had its uses of split locks stamped out, it hit this.

I tried adding `split_lock_detect=off` (see linked article) to the compiled-in command line (since I have no bootloader) but it appears that the code setting up split-lock detection runs before the code that brings in the compiled-in command line. Anyway, it stayed enabled.

So for my application I patched out the split-lock detection enabling in `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/intel.c`. There are probably better fixes, e.g. turning this feature off at kexec time, using a bootloader and the command-line disable, or not booting old kernels, but I did not want to attempt them.

Since this was kind of a weird problem I wanted to get it out on Stack Exchange in case this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I also saw this issue some time ago and have a patch to disable sld before kexecing.

https://github.com/chengchiehhuang/linux/commit/3e49acca98335c8969fa8af438fddbb8335e5b3c

*NOTE:* I tried to comment on your answer but the system does not allow a newbie to add comments :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community nonsense.